# Can I upload an audio file?

Tags: support, uploader, audio

Not sure where else to ask. There is no help or support forum?

Anyways, is it possible to upload an audio file, or how can I create a link to my machine, or is there a website to upload it to and then link it?

Comment: I would like to use it either on Gardening, Outdoors or Biology to upload an animal call, which I would like to identify (bird, weird cricket or else).

Comment: You might want to check with the sites to see if that's in scope for them. If it is, the only way you can do it at the moment would be to upload it to a third-party site and link to the file. I do know that people have done this on some other sites, like English Language Learners, so it's doable, just requires the audio to be uploaded elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks. Dropbox should work.

Comment: Related: [embedded audio player on language sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152282/273494)

Comment: @user20404 Some sites permit a link to a YouTube video, which would reveal a link from an account here to there (if it's your video), so for a birdcall you could show the bird in addition to playing the audio. --- It would be your responsibility (regardless of who owns the video) to maintain the link to a relevant video; lest you risk a Q|A deletion, and eventual ban.

Comment: Another duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238048/282094 - It was implemented, here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97610/282094. [Embed music](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298844/282094) from SoundCloud is enabled on: [Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3616/85493), [Music Practice & Theory](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/245/57957), [Signal Processing](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/83/37400), [Video Production](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/q/190/18314). Post on a site's [tag:per-site-meta], get votes, ask for it to be enabled.